# How to get a specific child in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In the simple example below, I'm looking for a way to get for example `CardBody` child.

```
const Card = ({children}) => {
  const cardHeadChild = ...;
  const cardBodyChild = ...;
  return (
    <div>
      {cardHeadChild}
      {cardBodyChild}
    </div>
  )
}

const CardHead = () => <div>Head</div>
const CardBody = () => <div>Body</div>

// Usage:
<Card>
  <CardHead>
  <CardBody>
</Card>
```

I cannot get by index (eg: `React.Children.toArray(children)[1]`) because children are optionals.

I tried something like this:

```
React.Children.forEach(children, child => {
   if(child.type.name === 'CardBody') cardBodyChild = child
   // or
   if(child.type.displayName === 'CardBody') cardBodyChild = child
  ..
})
```

but it doesn't work when component are wrapped in HOC.

Any solution ?

Comment: Where CardHead and CardBody come from? Are they your own functions? Is it guaranteed that children are only CardHead or CardBody components? *but it doesn't work when component are wrapped in HOC* - what exactly do you mean?

Comment: In this example, `child.type.displayName` will print `CardBody`. But if `CardBody` is wrapped in a HOC, it will print something like `someHoc(CardBody)`. Plus, I think in production mode it will print something random.

Comment: Your're right on your suspicions about 'something random'. Why would it be wrapped with HOC if `Card` expects strict hierarchy? HOC should possibly be applied in some another way. Please, provide an example with HOC.

Comment: why do you want to access the children, maybe there is a better solution to what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 9):

Function `name` shouldn't be used in production client-side code because function names are mangled when the application is minified. The same applies to `displayName` - unless it was set explicitly. Also notice that primary use of `displayName` and `name` is debugging.

Children can be identified by React element `type`. If the purpose is to output optional children in specified order, this can be done similarly to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51841787/3731501):

```
Optional head:
{props.children.find(({ type }) => type === CardHead)}
Optional body:
{props.children.find(({ type }) => type === CardBody)}
```

It's expected that children should be exactly `CardHead` and `CardBody` stateless components. If there's a need to enhance their functionality with other components, `CardHead` and `CardBody` should wrap these components:

```
const CardHead = props => <div>
  Head
  {props.children}
</div>

...

<Card>
  <CardHead><SomeComponent/></CardHead>
</Card>
```